# How can I remove a rectangle after a collision?

Tags: java, collision

I have two rectangles that I need to be taken off screen when they intersect. The rectangles I need to disappear are, bulletObject and e1. They do intersect when I run it but nothing happens. I have tried putting "e1 = new Rectangle (0,0,0,0);" after the "if (bulletObject.intersects(e1)){" but then it tells me that it is never used. All help I appreciated. A chunk of my code is below.

```
 public void draw(Graphics g){

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 40, 10);
    g.fillRect(x+18, y-7, 4, 7);
    Rectangle bulletObject = new Rectangle(x+18, y-7, 4, 7);
    if (shot){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(bullet.x, bullet.y , bullet.width, bullet.height);
    }
    //enemies

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    Rectangle e1 = new Rectangle(20,75,35,35);
    Rectangle e2 = new Rectangle(85,75,35,35);
    Rectangle e3 = new Rectangle(150,75,35,35);
    Rectangle e4 = new Rectangle(205,75,35,35);
    Rectangle e5 = new Rectangle(270,75,35,35);
    Rectangle e6 = new Rectangle(335,75,35,35);
    Rectangle e7 = new Rectangle(405,75,35,35);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(e1.x,e1.y,e1.width,e1.height);
    g.fillRect(e2.x,e2.y,e2.width,e2.height);
    g.fillRect(e3.x,e3.y,e3.width,e3.height);
    g.fillRect(e4.x,e4.y,e4.width,e4.height);
    g.fillRect(e5.x,e5.y,e5.width,e5.height);
    g.fillRect(e6.x,e6.y,e6.width,e6.height);
    g.fillRect(e7.x,e7.y,e7.width,e7.height);
    g.fillRect(bulletObject.x,bulletObject.y,
               bulletObject.width,bulletObject.height);

    if (bulletObject.intersects(e1)){          
        g.clearRect(e1.x, e1.y,e1.width, e1.height );

    }

}
```

Comment: Add your rectangles to some kind of `List`. Check what collides, remove those from the `List` and repaint...Think of painting like a painter painting onto a canvas, which you've painted something, it's much hard to get it off ;) - Also, what framework are you using...?

Comment: I am using Netbeans 7.3.1 and what do you mean when you say add them to a list? I am new to Java and I haven't heard of anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with...

Your paint routines is not the appropriate place to be making decisions about the state of the game, it should be simple responsible for painting the current state.

You need to maintain a `List` of renderable elements which you can manipluate based on your needs and requirements.

Start by taking a look at [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

You may also find reading through [Performing Custom Lainting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) useful

The following example demonstrates the basic concept of a series of animated, random, rectangles which will be removed when hit by a fireball, which you trigger by pressing the space bar

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Bullet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bullet();
    }

    public Bullet() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Rectangle> ships;
        private Map<Rectangle, Integer> delats;

        private Ellipse2D fireBall;

        public TestPane() {
            delats = new HashMap<>(25);
            ships = new ArrayList<>(25);
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (ships.size() < 12) {

                boolean intersects = true;
                Rectangle rect = null;
                while (intersects) {
                    intersects = false;
                    int x = (int) (Math.random() * 400);
                    int y = (int) (Math.random() * 400);
                    int width = (int) (Math.random() * 50) + 25;
                    int height = (int) (Math.random() * 50) + 25;

                    if (x + width >= 400) {
                        x = 400 - width;
                    } else if (y + height >= 400) {
                        y = 400 - height;
                    }

                    rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
                    for (Rectangle other : ships) {
                        if (other.intersects(rect)) {
                            intersects = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ships.add(rect);
                delats.put(rect, (rnd.nextBoolean() ? 1 : -1));
            }

            Timer timer;
            timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    if (fireBall != null) {

                        Rectangle bounds = fireBall.getBounds();

                        bounds.x += 5;
                        if (bounds.x >= getWidth()) {
                            fireBall = null;
                        } else {
                            fireBall.setFrame(bounds);
                        }

                    }
                    Iterator<Rectangle> it = ships.iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Rectangle rct = it.next();
                        int delta = delats.get(rct);
                        rct.y += delta;
                        if (rct.y + rct.height >= getHeight()) {
                            rct.y = getHeight() - rct.height;
                            delta *= -1;
                        } else if (rct.y <= 0) {
                            rct.y = 0;
                            delta *= -1;
                        }

                        delats.put(rct, delta);

                        if (fireBall != null) {

                            if (fireBall.intersects(rct)) {
                                it.remove();
                                delats.remove(rct);
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0), "fire");
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();
            am.put("fire", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    fireBall = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, (getHeight() / 2) - 5, 10, 10);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            if (fireBall != null) {

                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.fill(fireBall);

            }

            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (Rectangle rct : ships) {
                g2d.draw(rct);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are new to programming since you said you don't understand what a list is. I would suggest you check out the java tutorials available online (for instance for understanding lists and other collections: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).
As far as your question, I agree with MadProgrammer, you should have a list of objects which your draw function draws and when a rectangle is "hit" then you should remove it from this list.
For instance to create your list use:

```
List<Shape> shapeList = new ArrayList<Shape>();
Rectangle e1 = new Rectangle(20,75,35,35);
shapeList.add(e1);
Rectangle e2 = new Rectangle(85,75,35,35);
shapeList.add(e2);
//repeat for each rectangle
```

This shouldn't be in your draw method as this method will be called many times in your program I assume and you don't want to have to recreate this list and each rectangle every time you do this.

I suggest you look at the documentation for List and ArrayList and learn how to use them well since you will use them almost every time you write a program in Java. 
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

**Store your Rectangles in some kind of data structure** - if you know the maximum possible numer of Rectangles you may use an array. If not - a list would be a better choice as its size is not fixed (you just add and remove the elements to/from the list and do not care much about its size - you can read more about Lists here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html , online search should also be fruitful.)

**Once all your Rectangles are in an array or a list (or any other collection you choose) you can paint all the rectangles that are in the collection at the moment.** If two or more of them collide - remove them from the collection and repaint (so again paint all the rectangles which are in the collection now).

If all of this appear to be unfamiliar for you (arrays, collections...) I highly recommend you check out some Java tutorials (or general programming tutorials) - for example the official Java Turorial by Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/tutorialLearningPaths.html